# Magento 2 How to create table setting in admin system configuration?

Tags: magento2

According magento 1, we extend from "adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array" to create a table like this :
[image]

My question is : How we create it in magento 2 ?

Edit:
 Finally, with @Marius help : it's User-Agent Exceptions field in System=>Configuration=>General=>Design=>Design Theme.

[image]

We can create a new table configuration based on this field by looking at it's codes
"Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Regexceptions"

Comment: look into this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86147/config-value-not-rendering-in-magento-2/86275#86275 it will help out

Comment: Thank you. But I think the answer from @Marius is what I need.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it using, Company/Modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Under section -> group field

```
<field id="mapping" translate="label comment tooltip" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Customer Fields Mapping</label>
    <frontend_model>Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Customermap</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
    <comment>
        <![CDATA[Add the comments!]]>
    </comment>
    <tooltip>Map the magento customer field to custom module merge_fields</tooltip>
</field>
```

In frontend model file inside block,

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Customermap extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory
     */
    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_elementFactory  = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addColumn('field1', ['label' => __('Field1')]);
        $this->addColumn('field2', ['label' => __('FIeld2')]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

You have display table in configuration area and after saving its value are saved inside `core_config_data` table.

Comment: it's working fine. But when I save like `<test>` it is displaying `&lt;test2&gt;`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, having doubt, If  i wish to to add another group which consists same fields , frontend model, backend model which you have added in your system.xml then how Do I add another group with same system.xml file. while adding new group ,whether it will load the template properly ?

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya , Please have a look and answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212229/how-to-add-default-values-for-system-configuration-in-magento-2/212516#212516

Comment: hi @rakesh Jesadiya, i have added fields using above code but unable to save and there is error on console field(qty) not defined.

Comment: How to create the rows in this admin config table programmatically  ?

Comment: Its working fine.. how to add date picker within input field

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent for `adminhtml/system_config_backend_serialized_array` in Magento 2 is `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized`.
You can take as example the field `User-Agent Exceptions` from config and try to replicate it.
The field is defined in `Magento/Backend/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

Comment: Yes. It's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: hi @marius, i have added fields using code 
$this->addColumn('value', ['label' => __('Value')]);
$this->addColumn('qty', ['label' => __('Qty')]);

but unable to save and there is error on console field(qty) not defined Please help