# Magento2: how to add/remove a form field using javascript

Tags: javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, magento-2.2.5

I have created a **custom form** in admin in which I need to show buttons such as **"Add more"** and **"Remove"**. The scenario is exact that which is discussed here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903032/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento2-admin-form?rq=1

I created and added a child block but not getting how I can add or remove a field using **javascript**.

Please help ?

Comment: Check this and let me know is this what you require 
https://codepen.io/rsherry/pen/QwoqyO

Comment: I did this using jQuery only, but I was wondering how to do using knockout and Magento way.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x5wu7gsy/ Using knockout, hope this could help you.

Comment: You should try this way : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177529/how-to-create-a-repeater-field-like-minsaleqty-regexceptions-inside-admin-for