# How to add default values for system configuration in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, backend, system-config, default-values

**How to add default values for system configuration  in magento 2**.

**I need to create and assign default values for system configuration(system.xml) for my custom module**.

I have already created system configuations for my custom module.

**In ui-form I have a field(flieuploader) namely small image which contains
 **backend system configuration** which I have shown in below image**.

For below system configuartion
[image]

I have reffered to set system configuation like below using **\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray.php** and **\Magento\Config\view\adminhtml\templates\page\system\config\form\field\array.phtml**

**Now,It works good and the configuation is also saved in DB**. But I need **to create default values for my system configuration in config.xml. Please provide me a solution.

**In core_config table My system config value is stored in below format**
**for  small image**

> {"_1517563385604_604":{"width":"480","height":"300","imagesize":"25900"}}

*For imagefile type*

> jpg,jpeg,png,gif

**How Do I give this value in config.xml which is in default configuration**

**System.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>


<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="aaa" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>XXXXX</label>
            <tab>x_y_tab</tab>
            <resource>X_Y::config</resource>
            <group id="groupslide" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>YYYYY</label>
                <field id="small_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Small Image</label>
                    <frontend_model>X\Y\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>                    

                </field>

                <field id="image_file_types" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Image File Types</label>
                    <comment>Multiple values are seperated with comma</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/how-can-i-change-the-default-product-images-sizes-on-magento-2

Comment: Do you want to create a new system configuration value setting ?

Comment: @MGento, I have updated my question Please answer

Comment: I think you want to create default configurations for your image dimensions in Store=>Configuration=> Catalog . Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No. I have already created system configuartion for my custom module. Now Need to add default configuaration for my custom module

Comment: If user failed to enter dimensions means , Default dimensions will work.

Comment: Then you have to create a custom table for your module and store these values in your custom table.

Comment: No No. Please refer the link , I have created system configuartion in that manner only https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86147/config-value-not-rendering-in-magento-2?rq=1

Comment: Have a look in to the below post, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90795/magento-2-default-values-for-system-xml-configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72703/discussion-between-sri-and-mgento).

Comment: Could you please share your system.xml file?

Comment: I have updated the post @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: please share full system.xml file

Comment: I have shared my full system.xml. Please see the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create config values in config.xml, you can take reference about this from any module which add entries in configuration and to use it in your phtml, check for value in db and if value is not available or null, set the value from core/config.

Let me know if you need code reference too to get this sorted.

Comment: See the updated post ans answer.Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

Default value does not work with ArraySerialized in Magento 2.0.x – 2.1.x. Check this issue on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9038) for details. To resolve it you can use data installation scripts in `Setup/InstallData.php`. Sample function could look like this

```
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $index = time();
        $configData = [
            'section' => 'nwdarrayserialized',
            'website' => null,
            'store'   => null,
            'groups'  => [
                'general' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'responsiveItems' => [
                            'value' => array(
                                $index.'_0' => array("breakpoint" => "0", "items" => "1"),
                                $index.'_1' => array("breakpoint" => "480", "items" => "2"),
                                $index.'_2' => array("breakpoint" => "768", "items" => "3"),
                                $index.'_3' => array("breakpoint" => "1024", "items" => "5"),
                            ),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
 
        /** @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config $configModel */
        $configModel = $this->configFactory->create(['data' => $configData]);
        $configModel->save();
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks to you. As addition to this i suggest to see https://github.com/elpas0/magento2-configuration-arrayserialized
Where you can check how system.xml corresponds to install script. Moreover you can use UpgradeData.php as well with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I have solved my issue. simply I have updated my config.xml like below. Now the default value is set for my system configuration**

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <image>
                <groupslide>
                    <small_image>{"_1517915932157_157":{"width":"400","height":"300","imagesize":"25600"}}</small_image>

                <image_file_types>jpg,jpeg,png,gif</image_file_types>
            </groupslide>

        </image>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: you can also add default value in system.xml too where defining the configuration. This is also another way to do the same.

Comment: how can I add it in system.xml?? Can you share any example